# How to have PHP interact with an Access 2007 database directly?

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access, odbc

I have Access 2007 installed and I downloaded the Northwind Traders sample database which is easily available on the Internet.

I want to open connection with this database in PHP so that I can practice my PHP coding. I want to directly access the database without having to export it to MySQL and then accessing it.

I followed the following steps from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp  to achive that:

1. Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel.
2. Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
3. Choose the System DSN tab.
4. Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
5. Select the Microsoft Access Driver. Click Finish.
6. In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
7. Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
8. Click OK.

Then I tried the following code in php :

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('northwind','',''); 
if (!$conn) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}
?>
```

But it is displaying `"Connection Failed"`.

Please advise me how I can connect to Northwind database directly.

Comment: What is your OS? If it is 64-bit, verify that MS Access is also 64-bit. Otherwise the ODBC driver will not work.

Comment: Change your `exit` statement to `exit("Connection Failed: " . odbc_errormsg());` and then edit your question to tell us what it says.

Comment: If its just for practicing PHP I would advise to use pre configrued tools (my favorite is PHPStorm - best IDE, free, integrated Server/debugger etc. very easy to use with XAMMP which is also very easy to install) - like that you can be reasonably sure, any problem, that arises while programming PHP is from your code and not from some crazy undocumented Microsoft thingy. There is no worse way to learn something then when you never are sure if an error is in your code or in the server/driver.